# Services and authentication

Tags: services, 8

I can't authenticate with Drupal 7 and Services module. 
From REST client I send POST `{"username":"username, "password":"password"}` to user login endpoint.
I get sessid, session_name, token and user object.
I form header like:

```
Cookie: "session_name = sessid";

X-CSRF-Token: "token"
```

and after making GET to node I get:
["Access denied for user anonymous"]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK, I finally figured this out. I had module Basic Authentication enabled but disabled "session authentication" in options of Services module.